# VS 2017 Cannot find moment,JQueryPromise,JQueryEventObject & JQueryAjaxSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core

I have a problem in my ASP net core project, I just add adminLTE from bower, and update some bower installed package, after updating and installing I already encountered errors

already tried adding `tsconfig.json` in my project

TSCONFIG.JSON:

```
 {
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "amd",
    "allowJs": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

Error:

[Sample error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqknK.png)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript good works with NPM, and packages installed via it can be found by typescript automaticly. If you use bower, you should manually copy d.ts files from these libraries under your source dir.

Comment: What do you mean copy d.ts files from these libraries under your source dir? I am also encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude that plugin, it will be `executed successfully`. It's working for me. Right click on that plugin `(Ex:fullycalendar.d.ts)`, click on `Exclude from project.`